# Did I calculate the current correctly?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance

Are my calculations correct. I used Ohms law to find I1. And then KCL to find the remaining currents. I figured I3 would be a negative answer since the other current source would be supplying power that way.

[image]

Comment: Hello, you can used LTspice or some online simulator which all are easy to use to check your calculation

Comment: I do have LTspice. But I do not know how to put in the I1, I2 and I3 to check the answer.

EDIT: Found one that has an ammeter.

Comment: Install it. It’s free.

Comment: You can't have the output of a current controlled voltage source connected in parallel with a voltage source. Check your diagram. Better still, check the result with a sim as everyone else is telling you.

Comment: It is not a current-controlled voltage source? https://imgur.com/wjxeBRG

Comment: It must be a mistake in a diagram because it cannot by a current-controlled voltage source. Because you cannot have two ideal voltage sources connected in parallel. Therefore replace the CCVS with a CCCS (current controlled current source) and try again.